# Правильно передать данные в JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, jstl

Пытаюсь вывести данные из сервлета на JSP страничку. На сервере отрабатывает все как надо, редиректит на новую страницу, на которой должны появляться данные, но страница пустая. Есть 3 списка, каждый одинакового размера. На сервере они заполнены, если смотреть в отладке, а вот если смотреть в отладке в на самой jsp странице, то показывается, что эти списки пустые.

**Код сервлета:**

```
package com.example.farma;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(value = "/search")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html");

        String search = req.getParameter("serach");
        SeleniumFind sf = new SeleniumFind();

        Model framokopInfo = sf.findFramokop(search);

        req.setAttribute("Model",framokopInfo);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("newJsp.jsp").forward(req,resp);

    }
}
```

**Код основной JSP:**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>

</head>
<body>
<form action="search" method="get">
    <label>Введите ваш запрос
        <input type="text" name="serach">
        <input type="submit"
               value="Send">
    </label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Код Jsp на которой должна появляться информация:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:useBean id="Model" class="com.example.farma.Model"/>

<jsp:setProperty name="Model" property="*"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="Model" property="name"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="Model" property="price"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="Model" property="count"/>

<c:forEach begin="0" end="${Model.name.size()}">
    <c:forEach items="#{Model.name}" var="nameItem">
        <c:out value="${nameItem}"/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach items="#{Model.count}" var="countItem">
        <c:out value="${countItem}"/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach items="#{Model.price}" var="priceItem">
        <c:out value="${priceItem}"/>
    </c:forEach>

    <c:forEach items="#{Model.nameRecipe}" var="nameRecipeItem">
        <c:out value="${nameRecipeItem}"/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach items="#{Model.countRecipe}" var="countRecipeItem">
        <c:out value="${countRecipeItem}"/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach items="#{Model.priceRecipe}" var="priceRecipeItem">
        <c:out value="${priceRecipeItem}"/>
    </c:forEach>

</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Отладка в Jsp:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите почему так? Как правильно сделать передачу данных из servlet на jsp?

Отладка в Servlet:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где вы смотрите на отладке в JSP? Сделайте скриншот.

Comment: @RomanC добавил

Comment: Теперь добавьте класс `Model`.

Comment: @RomanC Прикрепил

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что вы смотрите в page scope, где создается  бин с помощью

```
<jsp:useBean id="Model" class="com.example.farma.Model"/>
```

В то время, как сервлет использует request scope.

Поскольку вы не указали откуда берется бин, то порядок поиска в JSP EL следующий:

```
page, request, session, application
```

Поэтому, чтобы избежать путаницы, и сократить время поиска бинов в JSP EL, следует использовать встроенные объекты:

```
pageScope, requestScope, sessionScope, applicationScope
```

соответственно.

То есть для вывода можно использовать

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="${requestScope.Model.name.size()}">
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.Model.name}" var="nameItem">
        <c:out value="${nameItem}"/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.Model.count}" var="countItem">
        <c:out value="${countItem}"/>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:forEach items="${requestScope.Model.price}" var="priceItem">
        <c:out value="${priceItem}"/>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Да, конечно. Вы ведь его не используете?